# Boxplot error with a substitute command that works fine with hist() and plot()

Tags: r, graphics, boxplot

I am asking your help to solve the following issue (and to help me understand the reasons the may have generated it).

I was trying to paste in a title of a boxplot some normal text, a symbol and the value of a variable.

I found on [this website](http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/) a simple way to do that, exemplified with some fake data and an histogram.

```
x_mean <- 1.5
x_sd <- 1.2
hist(rnorm(100, x_mean, x_sd),
  main = substitute(
    paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
    list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)
  )
)
```

I liked it very much, so I tried, and I got the result I was expecting. [image: Hist with title]

I tried to to the same with plot and again, it was ok.
[image: Plot with title]

I tried to do the same with a boxplot

```
x_mean <- 1.5
x_sd <- 1.2
boxplot(rnorm(100, x_mean, x_sd),
  main = substitute(
    paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
    list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)
  )
)
```

And I got the error:

```
Error in paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", 1.5, ", ", sigma^2, "=", 1.44,  : 
  object 'X' not found
```

Why?

What should I do to get the same behavior in boxplot?

Comment: Use bquote instead?

Comment: I would use `main = parse(text = sprintf('X[i]~N(mu==%s,sigma^2==%s)', x_mean, x_sd)` FYI jeroeroensons's comment about adding text can be addressed too: `parse(text = sprintf('"%s"~X[i]~N(mu==%s,sigma^2==%s)', 'A plot of', x_mean, x_sd))`

Comment: rawr (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr): cool your suggestion works. Small detail, the tilde is not printed between X[i] and N

Comment: Roland (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland): yes, I finally went for bquote with this `main = bquote( X[i]~"~N("~mu~ "=" ~.(x_mean)~sigma^2~ "=" ~.(x_sd)~")" )`

Comment: But still I wonder what is different in boxplot() compared to hist() and plot()

Comment: The tilde is required in this case to separate the string from `?plotmath`, if you remove it, there will be an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `plot`/`hist` and `boxplot` seems to be that `main` is passed directly inside `plot(..., main=)` but `boxplot` eventually goes through `bxp` which uses `do.call('title', list(main = ...)` to plot this text:

If you use `title` manually, it works:

```
x_mean <- 1.5
x_sd <- 1.2
boxplot(rnorm(100, x_mean, x_sd))
title(main = substitute(
  paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
  list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)
))
```

`boxplot` and `bxp` do this which gives an error

```
boxplot(rnorm(100, x_mean, x_sd))
do.call('title', list(main = substitute(
  paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
  list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)
)))
# Error in paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", 1.5, ", ", sigma^2, "=", 1.44,  : 
#   object 'X' not found
```

You can do this by hand just fine:

```
bxp(list(stats = matrix(1, 5), n = 1))
title(main = substitute(
  paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
  list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)
))
```

Or if `bxp` used `alist` (instead of `list`) so that the X wouldn't attempt to be evaluated:

```
bxp(list(stats = matrix(1, 5), n = 1))
do.call('title', alist(main = substitute(
  paste(X[i], " ~ N(", mu, "=", m, ", ", sigma^2, "=", s2, ")"),
  list(m = x_mean, s2 = x_sd^2)))
  )
```